# Error con fecha al cambiar el idioma del teclado

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, datetime, date-format

En mi base de datos tengo esta fecha:

```
5/22/2020 21:04:07
```

Sin embargo, la necesito en este formato:

```
22/05/2020 09:04:07 p.m.
```

Ya que con algunos dispositivos con otra disposición de fecha y hora, o lenguaje me da el siguiente error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Para solucionarlo lo intente de esta forma, pero sin buenos resultados:

```
var time24 = (snapshot.Get("FechaHora").ToString());
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(time24, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime a = DateTime.ParseExact(tiempo, formato, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Se usa la **clase CultureInfo** para establecer un tipo de cultura invariable, es decir "compatible" con cualquier formato.

Para usar la **clase Cultureinfo** debes poner en los **usings:**

```
using System.Globalization;
```

También podrías usar el **método TryParseExact**, el cual no lanza excepciones ni convierte fechas inválidas, digamos 31 de febrero, El **método ParseExact** si lanza una excepción cuando convierte una fecha inválida. Investiga más sobre como emplear el **método TryParseExact** en Internet.

Comment: Y ´formato´ en ParseExact será el formato de origen o el deseado?

Comment: @KennyAli hace un año la respuesta te habia servido, que fue lo que paso ahora?

Comment: Hola @Japv cuanto tiempo. Pues fíjate que lo probé pero me da el mismo error.

Comment: @KennyAli en 'formato' debes poner el formato adecuado